# IdentityServer 4, trying to capture traffic with fiddler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, identityserver4, openid-connect

Console application trying to get discovery

```
var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
```

Works fine, however i'm trying to figure out how this thing works and I cant seem to capture the http traffic.

if i use http://localhost.fiddler to redirect to the local proxy Errors With:

**Error connecting to localhost.fiddler:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration: HTTPS required (it's not setup with HTTPS, the error msg is misleading!)**

Strangely later in the code when we try to authenticate to web-api with

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost.fiddler:5001/identity");
```

localhost.fiddler works fine, now this is running in the same console.app, in program.cs so the same file. This is driving me potty why on earth can't I capture traffic going to 5000 it's HTTP!!! so what mysteries are causing this ? is there another way to view the magic http traffic going to and from Identity Server ?

Added Startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
}
```

added [Blog](https://donetcore.blogspot.co.uk/2018/03/identityserver-4-discovery-token.html), will update it and credit if we can resolve this.

Comment: What about `http://localhost.fiddler:5000` in the first place?

Comment: Does not work does not get to the api

Comment: What exactly does not work mean here? It throws an exception? or something else?

Comment: We get this error :Error connecting to http://localhost.fiddler:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration: HTTPS required  (it's not setup with HTTPS, the error msg is slightly incorrect!!!)

Comment: I think that is an important error, you should figure out why this happening? Have you configured certbot/LetsEncrypt? Some how it may be kicking in for some reason

Comment: where running on Windows, certbot is for linux/unix ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166191/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-saj).

Comment: Can you share your startup class?

Comment: Is this your own code or one from the IdentityServer4 quickstarts?https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts

Comment: I don't see the following line: app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

Comment: @aaronR this is not webapi it's identity Server

Comment: @saj does your implementation of IdentityServer have a login screen? If so the solution normally uses MVC.

Comment: @aaronR correct they do, but the early examples don't see GIT repo https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/Api/Startup.cs

Comment: @aaronR, sorry didn't see you earlier comment asking if this is my own, nope just working with the examples.thx

Comment: the link you just shared was for an API protected by IdentityServer and it had the call to add MVC app.UseMvc(); line 31.

Comment: @aaronR, my bad duhh! posted link to the API and not the Id server, this should be correct link now https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Startup.cs

Comment: ok, that is the minimalist sample with no login screen, which is far from a typical install. But that clarifies why no App.UseMVS().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly figured out, you need to use, for example, http://localhost.fiddler, to route localhost traffic through fiddler. However, using `DiscoveryClient.GetAsync` uses `DiscoveryClient` with default policy. That default policy has the following settings important for this case:

- RequireHttps = true
- AllowHttpOnLoopback = true

So, it requires https unless you query loopback address. How it knows what is loopback address? There is `DiscoveryPolicy.LoopbackAddresses` property. By default it contains:

- "localhost"
- "127.0.0.1"

For that reason you have "HTTPS required" error - "localhost.fiddler" is not considered a loopback address, and default policy requires https for non-loopback addresses.

So to fix, you need to either set `RequireHttps` to false, or add "localhost.fiddler` to loopback address list:

```
var discoClient = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost.fiddler:5000");
discoClient.Policy.LoopbackAddresses.Add("localhost.fiddler");
//discoClient.Policy.RequireHttps = false;                        
var disco = await discoClient.GetAsync();
```

If you do this - you will see disovery request in fiddler, however it will fail (response will contain error), because server will report authority as "http://localhost:5000" and you query "http://localhost.fiddler:5000". So you also need to override authority in your policy:

```
var discoClient = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost.fiddler:5000");
discoClient.Policy.LoopbackAddresses.Add("localhost.fiddler");
discoClient.Policy.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
var disco = await discoClient.GetAsync();
```

Now it will work as expected.

Comment: Hi this sounds very promising however i'm not seeing .Policy...Error 'DiscoveryResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Policy' and no extension method 'Policy'

Comment: @saj are you sure you followed code in answer? You need to replace 'var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");' with code from answer. Your error message suggests you are trying to call Policy on 'disco' variable, but that's not correct.

Comment: @saj plus, I tested posted solution and quite sure it works.

Comment: I don't doubt you, what you say makes perfect sense, which example are your working with must be missing a ref ?

Comment: Well I downloaded sample project by your last link in comment and edited Client as described in answer. Maybe  you can add exact lines that produce error for you?